# Hiding a button in a certain display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following data table where it has 2 control buttons, edit and save. The issue I am having is hiding the save button from the first preview.

(The output I am trying to achieve is on the first page it should only display Edit and when a user clicks on Edit it should display save.)

please see the snippet for further explanation.

```js
function edit_row(id)
{
 var name=document.getElementById("name_val"+id).innerHTML;
 var age=document.getElementById("age_val"+id).innerHTML;

 document.getElementById("name_val"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='name_text"+id+"' value='"+name+"'>";
 document.getElementById("age_val"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='age_text"+id+"' value='"+age+"'>";
 
 document.getElementById("edit_button"+id).style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+id).style.display="block";
}

function save_row(id)
{
 var name=document.getElementById("name_text"+id).value;
 var age=document.getElementById("age_text"+id).value;
 
 $.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'modify_records.php',
  data:{
   edit_row:'edit_row',
   row_id:id,
   name_val:name,
   age_val:age
  },
  success:function(response) {
   if(response=="success")
   {
    document.getElementById("name_val"+id).innerHTML=name;
    document.getElementById("age_val"+id).innerHTML=age;
    document.getElementById("edit_button"+id).style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("save_button"+id).style.display="none";
   }
  }
 });
}

function delete_row(id)
{
 $.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'modify_records.php',
  data:{
   delete_row:'delete_row',
   row_id:id,
  },
  success:function(response) {
   if(response=="success")
   {
    var row=document.getElementById("row"+id);
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
   }
  }
 });
}

function insert_row()
{
 var name=document.getElementById("new_name").value;
 var age=document.getElementById("new_age").value;

 $.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'modify_records.php',
  data:{
   insert_row:'insert_row',
   name_val:name,
   age_val:age
  },
  success:function(response) {
   if(response!="")
   {
    var id=response;
    var table=document.getElementById("user_table");
    var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
    var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+id+"'><td id='name_val"+id+"'>"+name+"</td><td id='age_val"+id+"'>"+age+"</td><td><input type='button' class='edit_button' id='edit_button"+id+"' value='edit' onclick='edit_row("+id+");'/><input type='button' class='save_button' id='save_button"+id+"' value='save' onclick='save_row("+id+");'/><input type='button' class='delete_button' id='delete_button"+id+"' value='delete' onclick='delete_row("+id+");'/></td></tr>";

    document.getElementById("new_name").value="";
    document.getElementById("new_age").value="";
   }
  }
 });
}
```

```html
<table align="center" cellpadding="10" border="1" id="user_table">
<tr>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>AGE</th>
<th></th>
</tr>

 <tr id="">
  <td id="name_val">Test Name</td>
<td id="age_val">Test Age</td>
  <td>
   <input type='button' class="edit_button" id="edit_button" value="edit" onclick="edit_row('');">

   <input type='button' class="save_button" id="save_button" value="save" onclick="save_row('');">
   
  
 </tr>
 <?php
}
?>


</table>
```

Comment: You could also use visibility:hidden property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this `css`.

```
.save_button{
  display: none;
}
```

or go for inline `css` `style="display:none"` for first display.

```js
function edit_row(id)
{
 var name=document.getElementById("name_val"+id).innerHTML;
 var age=document.getElementById("age_val"+id).innerHTML;

 document.getElementById("name_val"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='name_text"+id+"' value='"+name+"'>";
 document.getElementById("age_val"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='age_text"+id+"' value='"+age+"'>";
 
 document.getElementById("edit_button"+id).style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+id).style.display="block";
}

function save_row(id)
{
 var name=document.getElementById("name_text"+id).value;
 var age=document.getElementById("age_text"+id).value;
 
 $.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'modify_records.php',
  data:{
   edit_row:'edit_row',
   row_id:id,
   name_val:name,
   age_val:age
  },
  success:function(response) {
   if(response=="success")
   {
    document.getElementById("name_val"+id).innerHTML=name;
    document.getElementById("age_val"+id).innerHTML=age;
    document.getElementById("edit_button"+id).style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("save_button"+id).style.display="none";
   }
  }
 });
}

function delete_row(id)
{
 $.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'modify_records.php',
  data:{
   delete_row:'delete_row',
   row_id:id,
  },
  success:function(response) {
   if(response=="success")
   {
    var row=document.getElementById("row"+id);
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
   }
  }
 });
}

function insert_row()
{
 var name=document.getElementById("new_name").value;
 var age=document.getElementById("new_age").value;

 $.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'modify_records.php',
  data:{
   insert_row:'insert_row',
   name_val:name,
   age_val:age
  },
  success:function(response) {
   if(response!="")
   {
    var id=response;
    var table=document.getElementById("user_table");
    var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
    var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+id+"'><td id='name_val"+id+"'>"+name+"</td><td id='age_val"+id+"'>"+age+"</td><td><input type='button' class='edit_button' id='edit_button"+id+"' value='edit' onclick='edit_row("+id+");'/><input type='button' class='save_button' id='save_button"+id+"' value='save' onclick='save_row("+id+");'/><input type='button' class='delete_button' id='delete_button"+id+"' value='delete' onclick='delete_row("+id+");'/></td></tr>";

    document.getElementById("new_name").value="";
    document.getElementById("new_age").value="";
   }
  }
 });
}
```

```css
.save_button{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align="center" cellpadding="10" border="1" id="user_table">
<tr>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>AGE</th>
<th></th>
</tr>

 <tr id="">
  <td id="name_val">Test Name</td>
<td id="age_val">Test Age</td>
  <td>
   <input type='button' class="edit_button" id="edit_button" value="edit" onclick="edit_row('');">

   <input type='button' class="save_button" id="save_button" value="save" onclick="save_row('');">
   
  
 </tr>
 <?php
}
?>


</table>
```

Comment: `<input type='button' class="save_button" id="save_button" value="save" 
   onclick="save_row('');" style="display:none;">` this will be enough. Am i correct ?

Comment: Yup, This is also fine, if you have single row for table. But if you have more than one, got for first one

Answer (score 1):

Initially set the `display:none` for the Save button in your HTML Code like this following code,

```
<input type='button' class="edit_button" id="edit_button" value="edit" 
   onclick="edit_row('');" style="display:block;">
<input type='button' class="save_button" id="save_button" value="save" 
   onclick="save_row('');" style="display:none;">
```